# mysqlclient installation failing in python3 virtualenv(Mac OS)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Im trying to install mysqlclient inside a python3 virtualenv with the following command:

`pip3 install mysqlclient`

Here is the error I get:

```
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
```

What exactly is lssl? I tried `brew install lssl` but nothing like this exists.
Would love to get some help on this:(

Note: Im using python3.6.5

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install Command Line Tools

```
xcode-select --install
```